# Rename multiple files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I rename multiple files in eclipse and update their references as well ?

For ex. I got these classes in many packages in my project :

```
com.a.b.c.Fooclass1
com.a.b.c.Fooclass2 
com.a.b.c.Fooclass3
com.a.b.c.BarFooclass1
com.a.b.c.Dontworryclass
```

I want to replace `Foo` with `BAR`.
How can I replace `Foo` with `BAR` in the class names of all those classes in my project, which have `Foo` in their name.

**Edit** : I *really know* how to use refactor in eclipse for a single file ! I wanted to know a solution for multiple files.

Comment: Might be easier to write a script to do this. Just recur over your source directory.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to rename multiple source files at once in Eclipse. +1 to a script.

Answer (score 3):

This might help some other people crashing in here. If you wanna replace multiple file names use powershell:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter “*currentfilename*” -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.name -replace ‘currentfilename’,’newfilename’ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on file name -> Refactor -> Rename  -> Use the new name then press enter. Confirm any prompts. This will change any references. But I am afraid there is no way to do that for multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you in windows explorer, Select your first folder from the list, hit F2, paste or append to the file name, then hit tab, paste or append to the second file name, hit tab and repeat....